# Find Regex between two html tag

Tags: regex, expression

```
<form action="/facial-sas/#wpcf7-f158-p566-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form cf7-style" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="158">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.9">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f158-p566-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="566">
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<label>Select Department</label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-78"><select name="menu-78" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Stem Cell Treatments">Stem Cell Treatments</option><option value="Hair Restoration">Hair Restoration</option><option value="Face &amp; Body">Face &amp; Body</option><option value="Aesthetics">Aesthetics</option><option value="Vaginal Rejuvenation">Vaginal Rejuvenation</option></select></span>
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
<label>Your Name</label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-firstname"><input type="text" name="your-firstname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required full" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
<label>Phone</label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap phone"><input type="text" name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required full" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
<label>E-mail</label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required full" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<div id="cf7sr-5efbe15251408" class="cf7sr-g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" data-type="image" data-size="normal" data-sitekey="6Lcfm80UAAAAAARwri_XthNlglRc51eYQiyfEAGL"></div><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap cf7sr-g-recaptcha-invalid"></span><br>
<input type="submit" value="MAKE AN APPOINTMENT" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn full accent"><span id="wpcf7-5efbe1525136e" class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap honeypot-678-wrap"><label class="hp-message">Please leave this field empty.</label><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" type="text" name="honeypot-678" value="" size="40" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="nope"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none" aria-hidden="true"></div></form>
```

In above code  I want to find and replace between this two tag   first opening tag "<form action="

and closing tag   anything between changes on all my website pages. how do I select this all between this two tags and replace with some other code. please help me to find regex expression for find and replace in visual studio code.

thanks,
coder

Comment: <form action="    and </form> tag between this two tag I want to select data and replace in my HTML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this pattern `/(?<=[<fo]rm).+(?<![>])/g`

```js
str='<form action="/facial-sas/#wpcf7-f158-p566-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form cf7-style" novalidate="novalidate">'
pattern=/(?<=[<fo]rm).+(?<![>])/g
console.log(str.match(pattern)[0])
```